# Website View is too slow

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I've implemented a view in Drupal, with 'Ajax' option enabled.

How could I increase the speed of this website ?

it is a bit too slow... is this a normal speed for drupal ? (to open an article, load the content, filter the content...)

**Update:**

1) Also, saving the view settings from the back-end seems to be very slow

2) Filters (the first 2 are exposed, so they are not applied)

```
Search: Search Terms required [Exposed]
Taxonomy: Term exposed [Exposed]
Node: Type = Project
```

3) The links with titles with special fonts are not working (sorry, I haven't fixed this bug yet)

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how the view is built?  I'm particularly interested in which filters you have applied and what order they are in.  Including the SQL that is being built for you by views is also useful - that's available if you go to edit the view, select the display, and scroll down to see the sql displayed.

Comment: I've updated my question. I couldn't see the SQL query. I've selected edit the view, selected display and scrolled down but I couldn't see any sql code.

Comment: You have to enable the live preview and then click once on the preview button. Below the preview there should be the SQL query.

Comment: It is enabled. Sorry, I forgot to mention. I also tried to save the view again to see it, but nothing..

Comment: Then try the devel module, there you'll be able to see all queries for that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching my friend.
Try Boost module, it gives a great "results vs effort" ratio.
If you're still having issues with performance, move on to Varnish.

Your ultimate source for Drupal optimization should be: http://2bits.com

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is taking 9 seconds to answer for me on this page. That is unreasonably slow for Drupal under most circumstances.

Use the devel module to find out if it is the database or something else that is the problem. Enable the Drupal cache, if not already enabled and also enable js/css aggregation.

If only this view is the problem, then the generated query is probably horribly inefficent. You should analyze it and maybe override it with a better query and/or set some appropriate indexes on the involved tables.

If possible, install APC (php opcode cache) on the server, that helps with php speed.

Memcached can help a lot, but installing that is a bit more involved.

As already mentioned Boost gives an extremely high improvement if you have an infrequently updated site. It won't help for registered users, only for anonymous ones.